# Cannot convert value "Mon, 02 Nov 2020 06:39:24 PST" to type "System.DateTime"

Tags: powershell, datetime

I am trying to parse over an RSS feed to extract posts updated in the last hour using the following:

```
ForEach ($item in $items) {
If (($Now - [datetime]$item.updated).TotalMinutes -le 60) {
    $link = $item.link
    $updated = [datetime]$item.updated
    $finalnews = new-object PSCustomObject -prop @{link=$link;updated=$updated}
    $news += $finalnews
}
```

}

However, this keeps on failing with the error:

> Cannot convert value "Mon, 02 Nov 2020 06:39:24 PST" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

I believe this is because of the PST or PDT at the end of the date in the `item.updated` property

How can I reformat or replace the existing datetime within each item so this does not throw an error?

The property to be replaced or reformatted is:

```
$rssfeed.rss.channel.Item.updated
```

Thanks for any assistance or suggestions.

Comment: `$updated = [datetime]($item.updated -replace '.{4}$')`. What is the goal for the `$finalnews` `updated` property? What time zone should it be and what format should it be?

Comment: thanks, I would like the `updated` property to show as e.g Mon, 02 Nov 2020 06:39:24 - so without the PST or PDT timezone at the end. Where can I place the code you have suggested, the script seems to currently be failing on the IF statement line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compare times, you will want to compare them in the same time zone. You can use `-replace` to remove the last 4 characters (space plus zone letters) of a string.

```
$Now = Get-Date
$news = Foreach ($item in $items) {
    $time = $item.updated -replace '.{4}$'
    $converted = [timezoneinfo]::ConvertTime([datetime]$time,[timezoneinfo]::FindSystemTimeZoneById('Pacific Standard Time'),[timezoneinfo]::local)
    if (($Now - $converted).TotalMinutes -le 60) {
        $link = $item.link
        $updated = $time
        [pscustomobject]@{link=$link;updated=$updated}
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

There's no need for `+=` to append to an array. You can simply assign your array output of the `foreach` loop.

If your local time zone is PST/PDT, then you do not need to convert the time.

Since `$now` is a `DateTime` object, you will need to convert any date strings into `DateTime` objects first before doing comparisons or date math. So if you skip the `$converted` conversion step, then you must use `$now - [datetime]$time`.

Comment: Thanks, adding the `$time = $item.updated -replace '.{4}$'` works great, but I am still getting an error in the foreach loop on the if statement.  It's slightly different error now, stating `Multiple ambiguous overloads found for "op_Subtraction" and the argument count: "2".
At line:5 char:9
+     If (($Now - $time).TotalMinutes -le 60) {`

Comment: @terrahawk80 If you are doing `$now - $time`, then `$time` needs to be converted into `datetime` object first. So it should be `$now - [datetime]$time`.

Comment: aha, yes! I had omitted the `[datetime]`, thank you. I think this is all working now, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

**If you can assume that the time-zone-abbreviation suffix (e.g., `PST`) always refers to the *local* time zone**:

You can simply *strip the suffix* and cast directly to `[datetime]`:

```
# Sample input.
$dateStr = 'Mon, 02 Nov 2020 06:39:24 PST'

# Strip a 3-letter suffix preceded by a space, if present.
# If there is no such suffix, the input string is used as-is.
# Note: Resulting [datetime] instance has .Kind value Unspecified.
[datetime] ($dateStr -creplace '^(.+) [A-Z]{3}$', '$1')
```

Note that the result will be expressed in local time, but the resulting `[datetime]` instance will have a `.Kind` value of `Unspecified` rather than `Local` and such instances behave like UTC when you call `.ToLocalTime()` on them.

To ensure that you get `Local` instances that unambiguously represent a local time (albeit relative to the local machine's time zone), use `[datetimeoffset]` for the cast and use the resulting instance's `.LocalDateTime` property:

```
$dateStr = 'Mon, 02 Nov 2020 06:39:24 PST'

# Resulting [datetime] instance has .Kind value Local.
([datetimeoffset] ($dateStr -creplace '^(.+) [A-Z]{3}$', '$1')).LocalDateTime
```

**If feasible, working with `[datetimeoffset]` ([`System.DateTimeOffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTimeOffset))** rather than `[datetime]` ([`System.DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime)) is **generally preferable**, because `[datetimeoffset]` instances unambiguously represent a concrete, self-contained point in time.

---

**If the time-zone-abbreviation suffix can represent *any* time zone:**

Unfortunately, the predefined time-zone information objects returned by `[System.TimeZoneInfo]::GetSystemTimeZones())` do *not* contain abbreviations such as `PST`, for a good reason, however: there is no global standard for such abbreviations, so `PST` could refer to *different* time zones in different parts of the world.

This means that **you'll have to create your own mapping of these suffixes to the UTC offsets** they represent, such as `-08:00` for `PST`, if interpreted as the US `Pacific (Standard) Time` time zone:

```
# Sample input.
$dateStr = 'Mon, 02 Nov 2020 06:39:24 PST'

# Map time-zone abbreviations such as 'PST' to their UTC offset.
# IMPORTANT: Be sure to define mappings for all suffixes you may encounter
#            in your input.
$tzAbbrevToUtcOffsetSuffix = @{
  'PST' = '-08:00'
}

if ($dateStr -cmatch '^(.+) ([A-Z]{3})$') { # Time-zone suffix present.

  # Map the suffix to its UTC offset.
  $utcOffset = $tzAbbrevToUtcOffsetSuffix[$Matches.2]
  if (-not $utcOffset) { Throw "No UTC offset defined for timze-zone abbreviation: $($Matches.2)" }

  # Replace the suffix with its UTC offset in the input string.
  $dateStr = $Matches.1 + ' ' + $utcOffset
  # Tell ::ParseExact() below to expect a UTC offset.
  $formatSuffix = ' K'

} else { # No time-zone suffix.
  # Assume it is a local date without time-zone suffix.
  $formatSuffix = ''
}

# Use [datetimeoffset] for parsing, so we can create a [datetime] instance
# with .Kind 'Local'.
[datetimeoffset]::ParseExact(
  $dateStr, 
  ('ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss' + $formatSuffix), 
  [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture
).LocalDateTime
```